# Bayesian linear regression marginal likelihood dimension mismatch

Tags: regression, bayesian, marginal-distribution

Consider a standard Bayesian multi-output regression problem:

$X \in \mathbb{R}^n$

$W \sim \mathcal{N}(W; 0, \sigma_{W}^2I)$ (where $W \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n}$).

$Y \sim \mathcal{N}(Y; WX, \sigma_\epsilon^2I)$

The marginal likelihood of $Y$ given $X$ under this model is $P(Y|X) = \mathcal{N}(Y;0,  \sigma_w^2XX^T + \sigma_\epsilon^2I)$ (from e.g. http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/teaching/4f13/1920/bayesian%20finite%20regression.pdf), but as far as I can tell, this gives inconsistent dimensions: the covariance 'matrix' of the marginal is 1x1, but the dimension of $Y$ is $k$. Are we meant to interpret this as saying that each dimension of $Y$ is independently distributed with this distribution?

Thanks
Kris